# MobileFirst 7.1 Custom device provisioning

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'll create a Custom device provisioning.
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/authentication-security/custom-device-provisioning/

I want to use Java Adapter. But, Getting Started sample code( validateCSR() ) is only JavaScript Adapter.
Can I create validateCSR() by Java Adapter?
If possible, I'd like to know below.
  -How to write the authenticationConfig.xml?
     
  -How to write the Java Adapter(parameter of validateCSR method)?
      function validateCSR(clientDN, csrContent){}

Answer (score 0):

As you understood correctly, `validateCSR` is currently only supported in Javascript Adapters.

If you prefer to write Java code, there is a possibility to write the core of the logic in Java, within a Javascript adapter: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/javascript-adapters/using-java-adapters/